# Compile Timeout LATEX

Tags: compiler-errors, timeout, latex

I am writing my thesis and I just got a compile timeout using Overleaf to write my latex document online.

Can anyone have a look?

https://www.overleaf.com/2668476mjzqbz#/7068424/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I can see, just remove or comment out

```
\tracingall
```

in line 37.

The reason for the time-out in compilation is not because of an infinite loop, but because `\tracingall` takes too long to completely write all of the debugging information to the `.log`.

This might be covered under the **Fair Use Limits** in the Overleaf help on [Why do I keep getting the compile timeout error message?](https://www.overleaf.com/help/46#.VWByCPlViko):

> ### Fair Use Limits
>
> If you have a very large document, it may just take a long time to compile. If you sign up for a free account, and you are signed in when you are editing your documents, we will give your documents more time to compile than if you are not signed in. If this is still not enough, we offer even longer compile times on our paid plans. We have to set timeouts in order to deal with infinite loops, and also to ensure that we are fair to all of our users.

Comment: I emailed overhead they said it just that my file was too long too compile they upgraded my account. Thanks

Comment: I don't want to write a similar question, but could you see why my text is also being timed out? 
it's in portuguese.
https://www.overleaf.com/read/tfycyvkrhkyn#c36acb

Comment: @RuanCarloWeiersBritzke: I cleared the cache (Click on "Logs and output files" just to the right of "Recompile", then click on red button at the bottom called "Clear cached files") and then recompiled and it worked. Before that the compiling process failed at around Chapter 2, purely because of time-out. Not sure whether the project itself is becoming too large because of loading so many packages/tikz libraries. Make sure you only load what you need to stay within the compilation limit.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Werner, it seems, my project is already too large to be done in overleaf, Maybe because of the tikz packages. Maybe for other reasons.